# Posit session failing when I open a script with mapping code?

Tags: r, leaflet, r-sf

Why would a posit workbench session fail when I just **open** a script that contains code that has **maps** being created and run? (Spatial analysis code).

The script does not include the packages being loaded in (this is in another script which runs fine).

I'm using a project. When I open up the script, my posit session will fail. I can source in the script as part of my render and the session will not fail. It's just opening this script (and not running anything) that will cause my session to fail.

I have tried:

- uninstalling all my packages and reinstalling them with the spatial packages first, then installing all other packages without any dependencies that conflict with the spatial packages.
- having my posit cache cleared in order to get back into posit

Any help appreciated!

An example of the code in the script which is causing issues:

```r
## 3.1 - Load in shapefiles
sf_loc <- sf::st_read(
  paste0("/Shapefiles/",
         "area_123/")) %>%
  dplyr::select(
    area_1,
    geometry) # geometry column contains shape data

## 3.2 - Join data to shapefiles
sf_heat = left_join(heat_map_data, sf_loc, by = 'area_1') %>%
  
  # Convert foreign object to sf object
  # st = spatial and temporal
  sf::st_as_sf(.) %>%
  
  # Define CRS as 4326
  st_transform(., 
               crs = 4326) %>%
  
  # join lookup
  left_join(., lookup2) 
  

# Check the coordinate reference system (CRS) of an object
st_crs(sf_heat) 


# this creates an html tag for the map titles
tag.map.title <- tags$style(HTML("
                                 .leaflet-control.map-title {
                                 transform: translate(-50%,20%);
                                 position: fixed !important;
                                 left: 50%;
                                 text-align: center;
                                 padding-left: 10px;
                                 padding-right: 10px;
                                 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
                                 font-weight: bold;
                                 font-size: 20px;
                                 }
                                 "))


title <- tags$div(
  tag.map.title, HTML(paste("<font color='black'>My Heat Map"))
) 


# Colour palette function

pal_function <- function(indicator_name){
  colorNumeric(
    palette = c("#C5C3DA", "#3F3685"),
    domain = sf_heat$indicator_name
  )
}


# Create colour palettes for 5 indicators

pal1 = pal_function(ind_1)
pal2 = pal_function(ind_2)
pal3 = pal_function(ind_3)
pal4 = pal_function(ind_4)
pal5 = pal_function(ind_5)

# Create heat map ----
service.map <-
  leaflet(data = sf_heat) %>%
  
  # Add world tiles
  addTiles(
    urlTemplate = "https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
    options = providerTileOptions(minZoom = 8, maxZoom = 14)) %>%
  
  # Add shapes from shapefiles, for each indicator
  addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal1(ind_1),
              fillOpacity = 0.8,
              color = "#2e2e30",
              stroke=T,
              weight = 2,
              group = "ind1",
              label = ~paste0(area_1, ": ", ind_1)) %>%
  addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal2(ind_2),
              fillOpacity = 0.8,
              color = "#2e2e30",
              stroke=T,
              weight = 2,
              group = "ind2",
              label = ~paste0(area_1, ": ", ind_2)) %>%
  addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal3(ind_3),
              fillOpacity = 0.8,
              color = "#2e2e30",
              stroke=T,
              weight = 2,
              group = "ind3",
              label = ~paste0(area_1, ": ", ind_3)) %>%
  addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal4(ind_4),
              fillOpacity = 0.8,
              color = "#2e2e30",
              stroke=T,
              weight = 2,
              group = "ind4",
              label = ~paste0(area_1, ": ", ind_4)) %>%
  addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal5(ind_5),
              fillOpacity = 0.8,
              color = "#2e2e30",
              stroke=T,
              weight = 2,
              group = "ind_5",
              label = ~paste0(area_1, ": ", ind_5)) %>%
 
  # overlay groups is tick boxes, basegroups is select one only
  addLayersControl(overlayGroups = indicator_list,
                   options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE,
                                                  position="bottomright")) %>%
  addControl(title, position="topleft", className = "map-title") 

service.map
```